# JMenuItem problem. I have five. One of them compiles with no problem. The others are identical, yet they refuse to compile

Tags: java, swing, action, menuitem

for some reason, I am unable to compile this in Eclipse. The "quit" menuItem works and no other menuItem works. Why is that?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI{

private JFrame frame;

public GUI(){
    makeFrame();
}

//This method makes the overall GUI and adds panels, labels,
//buttons, and everything else to the GUI.
public void makeFrame(){
    frame = new JFrame("Tower Defense");
    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();

    makeMenus();

    JButton shootButton = new JButton("Shoot");
    contentPane.add(shootButton);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

//This method makes the menu and all of the items contained
//in the menu which is then called by the makeFrame() method.
//I also add the menuItem's various ActionLiteners here.
public void makeMenus(){
    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);

    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    JMenu actionsMenu = new JMenu("Actions");
    JMenu buildMenu = new JMenu("Build");

    menubar.add(fileMenu);
    menubar.add(actionsMenu);
    menubar.add(buildMenu);

    JMenuItem sellItem = new JMenuItem("Sell");
    JMenuItem quitItem = new JMenuItem("Quit");

    JMenuItem turretsItem = new JMenuItem("Turrets");
    JMenuItem minesItem = new JMenuItem("Mines");
    JMenuItem workersItem = new JMenuItem("Workers");

    quitItem.addActionListener(new QuitActionListener());
    sellItem.addActionListener(new SellActionListener());
    turretsItem.addActionListener(new TurretsActionListener());
    minesItem.addActionListener(new MinesActionListener());
    workersItem.addActionListener(new WorkersActionListener());

    fileMenu.add(quitItem);
    actionsMenu.add(sellItem);
    buildMenu.add(turretsItem);
    buildMenu.add(minesItem);
    buildMenu.add(workersItem);
}

//Main method. It creates a new GUI.
public static void main(String args []){
    GUI gui = new GUI();
}

class QuitActionListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

class SellActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

class TurretsActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

class MinesActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

class WorkersActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

class ShootActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 6):

It is not compiling because the actions listeners (like `SellActionListener`, for example) that you are providing (all bar the quit action) are not implementing `ActionListener`. The method `addActionListener` expects an object that implements `ActionListener`.

This:

```
class SellActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Needs to become this:

```
class SellActionListener implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

(along with the other action listeners)

### For posterity

These sort of errors can usually be figured out from the compiler feedback. When eclipse said that there were compile errors, you should be able to see the error details. I guess it would say something like *"class SellActionListener does not implement the interface ActionListener"* (or something along those lines). If you google that error message you might be able to find the answer faster that waiting for someone to answer your specific question.

Comment: or put all ActionListener together to one Class with testing for sources Object obj = e.getSource(); or call java.swing.Action +1

Comment: @mKorbel -1 for One-Big-ActionListener, +1 for Action (assuming one-per-item ;-)